# Nested class friend function access works in gcc and clang but not in msvc

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, friend, class-template

I have this program with a friend function defined inside the class, that compiles with gcc and clang but is rejected by msvc.

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
class Outer
{
     struct Inner;
     friend void foo(); 
};

template<typename T>
struct Outer<T>::Inner
{
  friend void bar(Inner) 
  { 
    //gcc and clang accepts but msvc rejects this 
    typename Outer<int>::Inner k;    
    std::cout << "bar called";
  }
};
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo called";
    Outer<int>::Inner i;
    bar(i);    
}
int main()
{
    Outer<int> outer;
    foo();
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Wxzaxv8xP)

Which compiler is right here according to the standard?

MSVC says:

```
<source>(14): error C2248: 'Outer<int>::Inner': cannot access private struct declared in class 'Outer<int>'
<source>(5): note: see declaration of 'Outer<int>::Inner'
<source>(14): note: see declaration of 'Outer<int>'
<source>(14): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
<source>(17): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Outer<T>::Inner' being compiled
<source>(14): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Outer<int>::Inner' being compiled
<source>(12): note: while compiling class template member function 'void bar(Outer<int>::Inner)'
<source>(22): note: see the first reference to 'bar' in 'foo'
Compiler returned: 2
```

Comment: Minor point: "inner class" isn't a thing in C++. In C++ a class that's defined inside another class is a **nested** class. It's not too big a deal, except that in some languages "inner" classes have special properties.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, I agree and understand. Just for layman/casual purposes or rather since the term "inner" generally does convey(in C++) that we are talking about "nested", I often use the former term. Though ofcourse as you said, technically accurate term is "nested".

Answer (score 3):

Gcc and Clang are wrong in accepting the program because a friend function defined within a nested class has no special access rights to members of the enclosing class. This can be seen from [class.nest](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.nest#4):

> Like a member function, a friend function ([class.friend]) defined within a nested class is in the lexical scope of that class; it obeys the same rules for name binding as a static member function of that class ([class.static]), but **it has no special access rights to members of an enclosing class.**

---

In other words, `bar` has no access to the private field `Inner` of `Outer<T>` and so the program is **ill-formed**.